# Issue in MySQL database access using PHP and an HTML form

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am having an issue with my code. I am trying to insert data into a MySQL table using an HTML form and and PHP. This is what I have for both the HTML form and the PHP code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Add record to MySQL InventoryItems database</title>
</head>
<body>
<form    action="http://localhost:8088/insertInventoryItemssql.php",method="post">
    <p>ItemName<input type="text" size="40" name="ItemName"></p>
    <p>PurchaseCost<input type="text" size="40" name="PurchaseCost"></p>
    <p>SalePrice
    <input type="text" size="40" name="SalePrice"></p>
    <p>NumberSold
    <input type="text" size="40" name="NumberSold"></p>
    <p>NumberInventory
    <input type="text" size="40" name="NumberInventory"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add Record"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP code where my problem seems to be:

```
    <html>
<body>
    <h1>Insert Records into InventoryItems</h1>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","abc123","inventory");

if (!$connect) {
    die("<h1>Could not connect to the database</h1>" .
        mysqli_error($connect));
}
printf("<h2>Connected</h2>");

$itemName = $_POST['ItemName'];
$purchaseCost = $_POST['PurchaseCost'];
$salePrice = $_POST['SalePrice'];
$numberSold = $_POST['NumberSold'];
$numberInventory = $_POST['NumberInventory'];
$sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO inventoryitems      VALUES('$itemName',$purchaseCost,$salePrice,".
"$numberSold,$numberInventory)";
printf("Insert query is %s", $sqlcmd);

mysqli_select_db($connect,"inventory") or die("<h1>Could not connect<h1>");
printf("<h2>Connected to inventory<h2>");

$numbupdated = mysqli_query($connect,$sqlcmd);
if ($numbupdated == 1) {
    printf("<p>Record added</p>");
}
else {
    printf("<p>Record not added</p>");
}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem seems to be in this particular line:

> $sqlcmd = "INSERT INTO inventoryitems VALUES('$itemName',$purchaseCost,$salePrice,".
>       "$numberSold,$numberInventory)";

The output when I run the code shows this:

[image: Output]

What exactly is wrong with the code that it won't insert the values and it just shows what is in the double quote? I am thoroughly confused here.

Comment: There's a typo in your `form` tag - there's a stray comma in `,method="post"`. Swap that for a space and see what happens.

Comment: find this line `$numbupdated = mysqli_query($connect,$sqlcmd);` and change it to this `$numbupdated = mysqli_query($connect,$sqlcmd) or die (mysqli_error($connect));` this will help you diagnose the issue

Comment: Thank you for the assistance guys :) I took that stray comma out before the method="post".  It worked. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlcmd = 'INSERT INTO inventoryitems VALUES("'.$itemName.'",'.$purchaseCost.','.$salePrice.','.$numberSold.','.$numberInventory.')';
```

please add the mysqli real escape function to the query.

hope that will help you!